# .htaccess redirect old html page with space in the name

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I've changed an html site to a WordPress installation.

The old .html links have been redirected to the right wordpress page. The old site, which was obviously build by a monkey, had a page /over ons.html. That's right, it had a space in the filename. So now, i'am getting external requests on /over%20ons.html. I can't figure out how i can solve this redirection problem in .htaccess. The page it has to refer to is /over-ons/.

This is my .htaccess so far:

```
RedirectMatch 301  ^/([^/.]+)\.html$ /$1/
Redirect 301  /over%20ons.html http://www.sterkermerk.nl/over-ons/
Redirect 301  /index.html http://www.sterkermerk.nl/
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The 2nd line contains the rule. I've tried to escape the %20, tried using regex in RedirectMatch, but I can't get it to work.

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mod_rewrite instead of mod_alias (`Redirect` statements) because you're already using mod_rewrite and they'll conflict with each other:

```
RewriteRule ^over\sons\.html$ http://www.sterkermerk.nl/over-ons/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://www.sterkermerk.nl/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)\.html$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

(replacing the `Redirect`* statements)

The URI is decoded before being sent through rewrite rules so you don't need to use the `%20`, just `\s` or `\` will match the space.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Jon Lin, i've updated my .htaccess with your code. But when I navigate to http://www.sterkermerk.nl/over%20ons.html it is still not working.

Comment: @veelen Actually, you don't even need the second rule, the first one should match everything

Comment: Then it is not redirecting to /over-ons/ but to /over%20ons/

Comment: @veelen you clear your browser's cache? All these rules work for me in a blank htaccess file

Comment: Yes I did. Dit you also mention it doesn't redirect to /over-ons/ but to /over ons/ (or /over%20ons/)?

Comment: @veelen yeah, the rules need to be re-ordered